# how to count maximum number of login attempts in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I want to count the maximum number of login attempts in javascript. I really doubt we can do it in javascript because every time I submit the form it will give me a new instance
of JS file and variables inside. So the previous login counter will be lost on the next form submission. Is there a way we can limit the max login attempts to 3?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. And no, do not use JavaScript for limiting login attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage), cookies or a hidden input element to keep track of the number of login attempts (remember the dates of the last three login attempts, and compare the dates with the current time).

However, do **not rely on JavaScript** for this purpose, as it's easy to circumvent this.

Comment: But cookies and hidden elements will be specific to browser session and htmform. In case user close that browser session and open new one, he can continue with login attempts even after 3 unsuccessful tries. Right?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. You should *not* rely on JavaScript. It's always possible to cheat it.

Comment: @MSach Cookies, hidden elements and `localStorage` is indeed limited to sessions. But **JavaScript is client-side**. There is no way to reliably keep track of some variable without any server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you will submit the page every time ok/submit button is clicked, there is no point doing this is javascript. If however you were checking the password in javascript it would make sense.
Having said that, checking passwords in javascript is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this but everything you save on the client side is insecure since the client can change the data (or even remove your counter so it restarts counting).

If you have a critical/sensitive application you should manage the login-attemps, and all other forms of login data you which to have, server-side where you control the content.